# How to create a Trajectory for a sprite

Tags: android, andengine, 2d-games

I have a ball and when i click on that, I want to show a trajectory or path through which the ball should go (like in angry birds) .
Currently, I have my ball `sprite` attached to a `body` which moves with a given velocity.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in Advance

Comment: your question was already asked here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/show-path-of-a-body-of-where-it-should-go-after-linear-impulse-is-applied and also here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62079/showing-trajectory-indicator

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszMotyczka